# С# задать значение переменной - вызвать метод

Tags: c#

Добрый день дамы и господа)
набросал тут вот такой код:

```
public abstract class TNCode
    {
        public static string skp;

        public static void TNSKP(WorkbookItem workbookItem, EditingEventArgs e)
        {
            var curBook = workbookItem;
            skp = Common.ExtractText(curBook, "RAZ1S" + (Convert.ToInt16(e.Cell.Location) - 16) + "GRC");
        }

        protected static void LoadCodesAndNames (string file, out string[] codes, out string[] units, out string[] names)
        {

            var lCodes = new List<string>();
            var lNames = new List<string>();
            var lUnits = new List<string>();
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            using (var f = new StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("SReports.Client.Reports.TNVED.txt")))
                while (!f.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var spl = f.ReadLine().Split(new[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    if (spl.Length == 3)
                    {
                        if (spl.Contains(TNCode.skp))
                        {
                            lCodes.Add(spl[0]);
                            lUnits.Add(spl[1]);
                            lNames.Add(spl[2]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            codes = lUnits.ToArray();
            units = lUnits.ToArray();
            names = lNames.ToArray();
        }        
    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как в LoadCodesAndNames запустить TNSKP? нужно чтоб переменная skp забрала новое значение.

Заранее спасибо)

Comment: У Вас скорее всего опечатка в коде codes = lUnits.ToArray();

Comment: там не особо важно получать код или юнит, функция работает) нужно просто вызвать public static void TNSKP в protected static void LoadCodesAndNames. Никаких опечаток в коде нет.

Comment: Так, а в чем проблема-то? Напишите вызов `TNSKP();` и передайте туда требуемые параметры)

Comment: Да вот в этом и проблема) что то я не пойму какие параметры передать) пытаюсь передать out skp - не хочет (

Comment: public static void TNSKP(WorkbookItem workbookItem, EditingEventArgs e, out string skp) указал вот так и  protected static void LoadCodesAndNames (string file, out string[] codes, out string[] units, out string[] names) 
        {     
            TNSKP(skp); Пишет - ни одна из перегрузок метода не принимает 1 значения.

Comment: А вы посмотрите количество параметров, требуемых в `TNSKP();` - `public static void TNSKP(WorkbookItem workbookItem, EditingEventArgs e)`

Comment: ну я так понял что мое TNSKP(WorkbookItem workbookItem, EditingEventArgs e, out string skp) и есть 1 параметр - указанный out string skp, и вызываю функцию следующим образом TNSKP(skp); ни одна из перегрузок метода не принимает 1 значения

Comment: Так надо перегрузку сделать на 1 параметр, а не на 3. TNSKP( out string skp), но тогда не будет работать ваша функция. Потому что нет workbookItem. А вообще, нет смысла туда передавать skp внутри класса, потому что данное поле является глобальным внутри класса.

Comment: Если не передавать туда вызов skp он считает его как NULL - не хочет считывать значение skp = Common.ExtractText(curBook, "RAZ1S" + (Convert.ToInt16(e.Cell.Location) - 16) + "GRC");